# アンカーリンクで別のページに移動できない

Tags: html

初歩的な質問で失礼します。
現在ホームページを作成中で、リンクの付け方で躓いております。

ホームページの階層は以下の通りです。`index.html` から `activitysummary.html` にリンクしたいです。

```
Lectureフォルダ
∟index.html
∟activitysummary.html
∟cssフォルダ
∟imagesフォルダ
```

HTML リンク部分抜粋

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="./activitysummary.html"></a>活動概要</li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

一見合ってるように見えますが、何がおかしいのでしょうか。ドメインを取らないと画面遷移できないとかありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="activitysummary.html">活動概要</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

としてみてください。

質問に書かれたHTMLでは、タグとタグに挟まれた部分が無いので、リンクが表示されません（無いものは表示できないですから）

Comment: この方法で解決できました。有難うございました。

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="activitysummary.html"></a>活動概要</li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

でダメですか？